# Negating Quantifiers Help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

I'm trying to understand how to negate a quantifier. I'm not that good at writing out a quantified logical statement either.

This is the statement: There is somebody that no-one is taller than.
This is the negation: ( ∀ y) ( ∃ x) x is taller than y.

Can someone explain how they found the negation?

This is what I attempted:

Negation: Everybody is taller than somebody.

∀ x: everybody

∃ y: somebody

( ∀ x) ( ∃ y) x is taller than y.

I'm getting it flip flopped. I don't understand why.

Comment: Because your negation statement is wrong. The correct negation is "everybody has somebody taller than him" or in other words, "everybody is shorter than somebody"

Comment: @cr001 why is "somebody" ∃ x? why is it x?

Comment: Because the "there exist" guy must be taller than the "for all" guys.

Comment: @cr001 so the x and y is based on the original statement?

Comment: No it's based on the negation. The correct negation is "everybody has somebody taller than him". Or "For everybody, there exists somebody taller than him."

Comment: @cr001 thank u so much, its starting to make more sense. I understand your negation now, but I still don't understand when u choose the x and y. To me it looks like "for everybody" is x and "somebody" is y (in the negation statement)

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are merely symbols. It's totally fine to write ( ∀ x) ( ∃ y) y is taller than x. The key is to understand the logic behind negation.

Comment: The problem that I posted was part of a "match the statement to the negation" problem. Another problem that was part of that problem was Nobody is taller than everybody. And the negation answer to that was ( Ex) ( Ay) x is taller than y. How do I know not to choose that one for the problem I posted above? @cr001 also sorry I don't have enough reputation to move this to a chat.

Comment: Again, think logically. "Nobody is taller than everybody"'s negation would be "Somebody is taller than everybody", or "there exists somebody that he is taller than everybody"

Comment: @cr001 why isn't it "there exists somebody who is taller than no body?" isn't it supposed to be the opposite?

Comment: Try to think this way. "Nobody is taller than everybody" means if I give you any guy, he cannot be the tallest in the group. Now think of the negation. It would mean I can give you a guy that is the tallest in the group.

Comment: @cr001 :o that makes so much more sense! thank u!

Comment: The rules are two: the negation of $\forall$, i.e. $\lnot \forall$, is $\exists \lnot$ and the negation of $\exists$, i.e. $\lnot \exists$, is $\forall \lnot$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use $h(\;)$ as the height measure.

"There is somebody that no-one is taller than." $\equiv \overset{\tiny\text{some one}}{\exists y}~\overset{\tiny\text{no(t) one}}{\neg\exists x} ~\overset{\tiny\text{is taller than (the some one)}}{(h(x){>}h(y))}$

Negate it: $\neg\exists y~\neg\exists x ~(h(x)>h(y))~~\equiv ~~\forall y~\exists x~(h(x){>}h(y))$

That is "Everyone has someone that is taller than them", or "Everybody is *shorter* than somebody."